NAT gateway: incoming traffic?
I am a bit confused about NAT gateway.
NAT gatway is used when an instance in private subnet needs to talk to public internet, like for downloading a software patch. NAT gateway is said to allow only outgoing traffic. But if that's the case then how would patch be downloaded as it would need incoming traffic from public internet, isn't?

It only proxies outgoing traffic, and the response to that traffic. When something makes an outgoing request, a TCP connection is opened, and that TCP connection is held open to receive the response. The NAT Gateway knows how to send that response back to the resource in the VPC, because the response came back on the same TCP connection that the request was sent from.
NAT Gateways do not handle incoming traffic that originated as an incoming request. If you made a request from your laptop to the NAT Gateway, the NAT Gateway would have no idea what resource inside the VPC to forward that network traffic to, and it has no way to configure that sort of thing.

Ok, got it. Key is origin of request. NAT allows any traffic for which request originated from within VPC.
